# Problema con {{title}} en AngularCLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Estoy tratando de ejecutar el app.component.html que esta por defecto en la documentacion de Angular, pero el contenido de la variable title no aparece, sino que literal aparece {{title}} al ejecutar este archivo.

[image: Imagen de lo que muestra al ejecutar app.component.html]

Por que sucede esto?
Nota: Estoy usando VisualStudioCode

Comment: Hola, comparte el código de tu component

Comment: Sin ver el que codigo que has hecho poco se te puede ayudar

Comment: En la linea 344 de app.component.html debe estar definida la expresión {{title} la cual representara a la propiedad definida en la linea 9 de app.component.ts  title='angular' si es asi en tu proyecto por error  puede ser que o bien modificaste algo en app.component.html o instalaste alguna libreria .Proba declarar otra propiedad en app.component.ts por ejemplo hola='que tal' y trata de representarla en la linea 483 de app.component.html mediante {{hola}} y contame si podes que ocurrio

Comment: El problema es que estas abriendo directamente el archivo `app.component.html` en tu navegador y por tanto te muestra su contenido tal cual. Para que la app funcione como esperas tienes que compilarla previamente. Para ello puedes  utilizar en la consola los comandos de la cli `ng serve` o `ng build`. El primero a parte de compilarla te la servirá en `localhost:4200`